# Select column as variable

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo

I have no clue how to do this. I've looked up examples but it is all kind of vague for me using the @variable, I have no clue on what that is and how I can look up my answer.

I've got this variable `$slotname` which can be `weapon` or `amulet` or anything. 
In my database it is `weapon_name` or `amulet_name` thats why the `._name.` after the `post`

```
$slotname = $_POST['slot'].'_name';
$naam = 'Player1';
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT @slotname FROM player WHERE naam = :naam");
$sql->execute(array(":naam" => $naam));
$fetch = $sql->fetch();
```

So in this case `$slotname = weapon_name` and I want to select the column `weapon_name` from the user `Player1` but I have no clue how to do this.
Any tips?

Comment: $db->query("SET @slotname=$slotname"); before prepare statement

Comment: Because of the way parametrised/prepared queries work, you cannot bind a value to the columns select or the table it's selecting from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your database structure is essentially wrong.

There should be no such thing like `slot_name` field.

there should be a distinct table **slots** where all the slots have to be stored, and **selected by values, not field names**.

Comment: And how do I do that? Every `slot` needs a name and a value. For example `weapon_slot` `3` `amulet_slot` `2` I have no clue what you mean by your answer. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: It's already clear - another table. that consists of columns `char_id`,`slot`,`item_id`. From this table you can easily select any equipment

Answer (score -2):

```
sql = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$slotname." FROM player WHERE naam = :naam");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: not working @netham it just returns the same name. When $slotname = weapon_name it returns this : Array ( [weapon_name] => weapon_name [0] => weapon_name ) while it should return Array ( [weapon_name] => golden sword [0] => golden sword )

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I know, but maybe if you see the question and the answer, putting any explanation won't help. It's that simple. If it can, and you believe in it, I welcome you to use the edit button, and edit answers, before simply downvoting because you saw a code only answer. Is it always black and white? No, i guess.

Comment: @answer_me Give it a try now. I made a slight change. The basic idea is to concatenate and get a string. Try to echo that string and see what query form you are getting.